# how to find who disabled the index? The question is not about UNUSABLE index

Tags: oracle, index

I have an Index which gets disabled always. Whenever I enable it, then it will goto disable state. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Maybe you need to share your table schema

Comment: reiterating: Please modify your post to include the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements. also, post your 4 digit version number ( eg 11.2.0.4 ). thx

Comment: And how soon after you enable it?  Immediately?  After Oracle housekeeping daily tasks? After some mysterious batch process runs?